# Como buscar un valor en un dataframe y tomar el valor de una variable de ese df en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo valores en un dataframe que debo buscar en un segundo dataframe y tomar el valor de una variable de este último.

Es algo similar a la función buscarv de excel.

El primer data frame es algo así:

```
angulos <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, valor = c(10,235,179.4,16))
```

El segundo dataframe es este:

```
sec <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            sectores = c("NNE","NE","ENE","E",
                   "ESE","SE","SSE","S","SSW","SW","WSW","W","WNW",
                   "NW","NNW","N"),
            V2 = c(33.75,56.25,78.75,
                   101.25,123.75,146.25,168.75,191.25,213.75,236.25,
                   258.75,281.25,303.75,326.25,348.75,11.25))
```

Lo que necesito realizar es buscar los valores del df `angulos` en el df `sec` que coincida o esté cercano a un valor de la variable `V2`, tomar el valor de la variable `sectores` y colocarlo en una nueva variable en el df `angulos` junto a su valor correspondiente.

De tal manera que el resultado quede algo similar a esto:

| valor | sector |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | NNE |
| 235 | WSW |
| 179.4 | S |
| 16 | NNE |

La búsqueda no la realiza exacta sino que busca el valor más cercano y eso lo asocia con el valor de la variable `sectores`.

Buscando en otros posts, la solución la plantean con `left_join` pero en este caso no existe una columna común en los dos df, por lo que no es aplicable.

Les agradecería si me brindan ayuda para encontrar la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un enfoque bien básico con R base, la idea es: por cada fila de `angulos` ubicar el valor más cercano en `sec` y luego sí hacer un "join" de los dos `data.frames`:

```
valores <- sapply(1:nrow(angulos), FUN=function(i) sec$V2[which.min(abs(angulos$valor[i] - sec$V2))][1])
merge(cbind(angulos, V2=valores), sec, by="V2", all.x=TRUE)

      V2 valor sectores
1  11.25  10.0        N
2  11.25  16.0        N
3 168.75 179.4      SSE
4 236.25 235.0       SW
```

Otro enfoque, un poco más "elegante" aunque no necesariamente más performante es usar `dplyr/tidr`, hacer un producto cartesiano entre ambas tablas y filtrar los valores que sean más cercanos:

```
library(tidyverse)

angulos %>% 
  left_join(angulos %>% 
              crossing(sec) %>% 
              group_by(valor) %>%
              filter(abs(valor-V2) == min(abs(valor-V2))),
            by = "valor")


# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   valor [4]
  valor sectores    V2
  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
1   10  N         11.2
2   16  N         11.2
3  179. SSE      169. 
4  235  SW       236.
```

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que en mi df original `valor` tengo otras variables que tienen `NAs` y cuando aplico la solución planteada, me elimina las filas con `NAs`.
Cómo puedo evitar que las elimine?

Comment: Con la primera alternativa, puedes agregar el parámetro ` all.x=TRUE` la segunda  hay que agregar un `left_join()`

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la adaptación del primer enfoque para extraer los valores más cercanos iguales o menores?

Comment: @JoséCarlos. no entiendo muy bien tu comentario pero en todo caso ¿por que no haces una pregunta en el sitio?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/510442/obtener-los-valores-m%c3%a1s-cercanos-que-sean-iguales-o-menores