# Obtener los valores más cercanos que sean iguales o menores

Tags: r

Partiendo de los elementos de un vector:

```
cuartilin <- c(7.157005,43.899484,54.361137,69.247565,264.413889)
```

Y una variable de un dataframe

```
dfv <- data.frame(variable = c(7.157005,8.314364,8.353196,13.470627,21.696288,24.245269,36.784279,39.195120,41.664000,42.631196,44.322246,45.047203,48.957792,49.482210,50.580542,52.680045,52.815305,52.955818,53.812210,53.981087,54.741187,55.758900,57.754522,58.171500,62.616087,62.793654,63.969264,65.684746,66.437549,69.228131,69.305867,70.666772,70.929404,88.111394,89.767651,100.428632,117.751045,132.549124,153.454057,264.413889))
```

**Se quieren obtener los valores más cercanos que sean iguales o menores** de `cuartilin` **que se encuentran en la variable** `dfv$variable`

Utilizando este código[1] obtengo los valores más cercanos ya sean menores, iguales o superiores:

```
diferenciao <- dfv[sapply(
     1:length(cuartilin), 
     FUN=function(i) 
         which.min(
             abs(cuartilin[i] - dfv$'variable')
         )
 ),]
diferenciao
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**:
¿Cómo podríamos solucionar el problema añadido de que existan valores "NA"?, el código propuesto en la propia pregunta también resuelve la búsqueda de los valores más cercanos a los elementos del vector `cuartilin`, aún cuando existan valores `NA`, en `dfv$variable`.

La nueva definición de `dfv$variable` incluye valores `NA`:

```
dfv <- data.frame(variable = c(7.157005,54.741187,50.580542,NA,62.793654,NA,24.245269,100.428632,53.812210,52.680045,264.413889,44.322246,117.751045,69.228131,21.696288,58.171500,36.784279,63.969264,42.631196,132.549124,48.957792,57.754522,NA,52.815305,45.047203,39.195120,70.929404,NA,41.664000,65.684746,55.758900,8.314364,89.767651,NA,52.955818,69.305867,66.437549,53.981087,153.454057,62.616087,70.666772,8.353196,88.111394,13.470627,49.482210))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
sapply(cuartilin, 
       FUN=function(x){
         y <- dfv$variable[dfv$variable <= x]
         v <- y[which.min( x - y)[1]]
         which(v == dfv$variable)
       }
)
```

Básicamente: 1) filtramos valores menores o iguales 2) buscamos aquellos más cercanos 3) obtenemos la posición dentro de `dfv$variable`

Comment: Gracias @patricio-moracho, tu respuesta soluciona a la perfección la pregunta, tal y como está planteada inicialmente. Sin embargo he añadido una cuestión adicional, para cuando la variable ```dfv$variable``` incluye valores ```NA```.

Comment: @JoséCarlos, verifica mi última edición

Comment: No es una solución aplicable a este caso con valores ```NA```.

Comment: ¿Que esperas que se haga con los NA?

Comment: El resultado de aplicar el script de la respuesta a ```cuartilin 7.157005  43.899484  54.361137  69.247565 264.413889``` y ```dfv$variable``` es ```[1]  7.157005 62.793654 36.784279 53.812210 53.812210``` y debería ser ```7.157005 42.631196 53.981087 69.228131 264.413889```. Si se aplica el script de la pregunta, más cercanos aunque sean mayores, el resultado es ```[1] "  7,16" " 44,32" " 54,74" " 69,23" "264,41"```

Comment: "Obviando los decimales", he cogido la salida directamente de RStudio donde añado formato al resultado.

Comment: En el ejemplo de `dfv$variable` que pones en tu comentario  no hay un valor 44.32 ni 54.74 ni 69.23

Comment: De todas formas. revisa mi último cambio, para autorecordar: `wich.max()` retorna índices no valores

Comment: Los valores sí están incluidos en la pregunta tanto en la definición sin elementos ```NA``` como en la definición con valores ```NA```. El primer [1] se corresponde a aplicar el anterior script propuesto en tu respuesta a ```cuartilin``` y ```dfv$variable``` (no son los valores de ```dfv$variable```)

Comment: ¿Probaste mí ultima edición  (de hace minutos)?

Comment: Con la última actualización de tu respuesta se obtiene el resultado esperado. Sin embargo incluiré una nueva actualización con el código completo original porque no consigo adaptarlo. He intentado simplificar la pregunta.

Comment: Por cierto, agradezco mucho tu ayuda.

Comment: El problema con el último script propuesto en la respuesta es que no devuelve las posiciones en el dataframe ```dfv``` de los elementos que cumplen la condición, sino los valores de ```dfv$variable```.

Comment: Y por otro lado, ```y``` es un subconjunto de ```dfv``` por lo que el índice es distinto del dataframe inicial.

Comment: Mira mi nueva edición

Comment: Sos Grande, muy grande.